What is a good approach to calculate the median of weighted data using SQL?
TL;DR: I've got a column for test metric, for control metric, and for test-control weight. I can use the weight to calculate a weighted average. How should I approach median metrics in a SQL environment? It has to be SQL because my downstream users only have SQL in their compute environments.
The full story
I am doing a test-control read of store performance. I've been given a test-control design of 22 test stores, each with 10 control stores. Each row of data counts for 1/10 weight so that the sum of weights for each test store is 1.0 and the sum of weights for each test store's control set is 1.0. Textbook, right?
The problem is that a number of control stores cannot be used anymore so some stores have 6 matches, some 7, some 9 and the rest 10 matches. I calculate a weight of 10/(number of control stores) and calculate weights in SQL using:
/*** PSEUDOCODE ***/
SELECT location, 
       metric_name, 
       avg(metric_value) unwtd_avg
       sum(metric_value * weights)/sum(weights) wtd_avg
FROM testcontrol
group by location, metric_name

This works fine. How do I do the same for median using weighted data?
The brute force method I thought of is: my weights are to the 3rd decimal, so I multiply each weight value by 1000 and I have a round number, so I explode the dataset by the number of rows given by 1000 * weights and take the median.
I tried to apply the weight in the same way, where the SQL median function is:
approx_quantiles(metric_value, 4)[OFFSET(2)]
And modifying for the weight
approx_quantiles(metric_value * weight, 4)[OFFSET(2)]
But this didn't validate and I wouldn't expect it to - it's modifying the value of the row, not which row is the median value.

Show an example of the data, what kind of result you get and what kind of result you want to get.

avg(metric) and group by metric - It's not clear why. If group by metric avg(metric)=metric.

@ValNik, my bad. I break my data by location and metric, so the aggregation is on the metric's value. Similar to
"Store 105, Metric Total Sales, Metric Value 9100.55"

This question would get answers if you would show sample data and expected result
